# is BrightStarDB will support Ado.net in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, brightstardb

I am very new to BrightstarDB. i saw many expales like brightstarDB with Entity framework. I need to know weather BrightStarDB can be implemented by ADO.net? if yes please give me any link which helps me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

BrightstarDB implements its own "entity framework" - it is not based on or really related to ADO.NET in any way (other than it lets you do the same sort of things). You can read more about the BrightstarDB entity framework [here](http://brightstardb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Entity_Framework/).